# View with union all not to use table scan

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view (myView) with union all on 3 tables. Those 3 tables have more or less similar columns. But all of them has CreatedDate column.
When I perform

```
SELECT TOP 10 … FROM myView WHERE (CreatedDate >= '2020-01-01 22:00:00' AND CreatedDate <= '2020-06-26 21:00:00') ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
```

I have such execution plan. Having millions of records in table2, this is extremely slow.

[image]

I tried to create non clustered index on CreatedDate DESC in each table, but it’s still table scan. Including all the data into index’ included columns – not an option since 1 column is xml column with a lot of data.
Is there any way to make this fast or use that index?

Comment: Provide the *full* DDL for your `VIEW` along with the DDL of your tables and their relevant indexes.

Comment: Please provide the execution plan in text form. The images exclude important tooltip information we can't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use CTE in order to select before only clustered index columns that are always included in the non clustered index and after
do a join with the view including the other columns as below:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT TOP 10 (ONLY PK_CLUSTERED )
FROM 
          myView     
WHERE 
           (CreatedDate >= '2020-01-01 22:00:00' 
           AND CreatedDate <= '2020-06-26 21:00:00')     
ORDER BY  
           CreatedDate
) 
SELECT C.*, V.Column1, V.Column2, 
FROM
         CTE C
          INNER JOIN myView V ON V.PK_CLUSTERED = C.PK_CLUSTERED
```

Alternately you can modify your index including the columns that you are selecting... something like:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_table_CreatedDate 
ON YourTable
(
     CreatedDate ASC
)
INCLUDE 
(
    Column1
    ,Column2
    ,Column3
)
GO
```